# Custom NHibernate entity persister for modifying generated SQL statements

Tags: sql, nhibernate, interceptor

What I need is to populate entity from DB view (non-insertable) and make all entity updates to updatable DB table.

1. Mapping entity to table and writing custom load SQL from view is not an option since in some cases NHibernate still tries to select from table name (when joining this entity, for example).
2. Mapping entity to view and writing custom data modification queries is not an option since I can not write cross-database sql-insert statement (because of the last inserted identity value selection part).

The only idea I came up with for now is to modify generated SQL statements on-the-fly. I managed to do it with custom interceptor but I don't think that its a good idea (since I intercept every single query, even for other entities). However, I think that it should be possible to change only needed queries using custom `IEntityPersister`. I created one based on `SingleTableEntityPersister`, specified it in `<class persister="…">`, but NHibernate doesn't even want to instantiate it.

Are there any examples of writing custom entity persisters for NHibernate?

Comment: Could you have two mappings instead, and always save via one and select via the other?

Comment: That would require unnecessary SELECT statement executed to load updatable entity when it's needed to update it even though selectable entity is already loaded.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this or did you stick with a custom interceptor as I have exactly the same problem?

Comment: @Matt Unfortunately, no solution.